# sling models not loaded and imported packages are none in system/console/bundles despite import-package declarations in manifest headers

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I am trying to create HTL/Sightly component using sling models in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.1, but facing difficulties in getting sling model working.  System Console for Bundles is showing Imported Packages as None even though the manifest headers for my sling-models-bundle properly contain all the import-package declarations.

i checked in system/console/sling-adapters - my sling model class is not present there. i verified in the logs that the PostContruct annotated method is not called. I read somewhere that the AEM/Sling instance may be missing "Sightly Sling Models Use Provider", so i embedded that in my bundle but it did not help.

could someone shed some light on situations in which the OSGI runtime (here - felix) does not import packages declared in the manifest header for import-package?

Here are the export-package, import-package and sling-model-packages declarations

```
<Export-Package>
    com.company.project.model
</Export-Package>

<Sling-Model-Packages>
    com.company.project.model
</Sling-Model-Packages>

<Import-Package>
    javax.inject;version="[0,2)";resolution:=optional,
    !org.apache.log,
    !org.apache.avalon.framework.logger,
    *;resolution:=optional
</Import-Package>
```

Comment: can you provide your code package snippet.? if you are using maven is your `maven-bundle-plugin` **<Export-Package>** tag is having the entries of your package that are needed into Felix.?

Comment: you may find my sling-models-sample repo useful: https://github.com/mickleroy/sling-models-sample

Comment: can you post your full pom.xml?
Also, you set `*;resolution:=optional` which means all packages resolve optionally.